# What is a word used to describe something that 'wasn't meant to be'

Tags: phrases, expressions

I looked up this phrase on Google and got basically no clear results.

What does this phrase mean and which context is it used in?

Comment: :) It's an expression that implies that something (usually a relationship) didn't work because of no one's fault but fate.

Comment: Hahaha, question closed as off-topic, with one negative vote, but viewed 10,000 times (more than most of the on-topic questions ever on this site)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***It (just) wasn't meant to be*** derives from the idiom ***meant to be***, which means "destined to exist" ([here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/meant+to+be)).

People say that something (for example, an event) was "meant to be" when they want to attribute that thing to fate or destiny. It is a fatalistic expression.

To say that something (for example, an event) "wasn't meant to be" means that the thing was *not* destined to happen (or that it was destined to *not* happen). It attributes the thing's not happening to fate or destiny.

It has roughly the same meaning as the idiom ***it just wasn't in the cards***.